# Logical error in code?

Tags: python

> QUESTION:
>   The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>
> Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from left to right and right to left. NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

My code is only able to output first five such numbers and shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 41, in 
    if check(i) and check(rev(i)):
  File "main.py", line 30, in check
    if sieve[n]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
sieve = [True] * 1000001 # Sieve is faster for 2M primes
def mark(sieve, x):
    for i in xrange(x+x, len(sieve), x):
        sieve[i] = False
sieve[0],sieve[1]=False,False
for x in xrange(2, int(len(sieve) ** 0.5) + 1):
    if sieve[x]: mark(sieve, x)


def rev(n):
  s=0
  while n>0:
    s=s*10+n%10
    n/=10
  return s

def check(n):
  flag=1
  while n>0:
    if sieve[n]:
      n/=10
    else:
      flag=0
      break
  return flag==1

ctr=0
i=11
s=0
while ctr!=11:
  if check(i) and check(rev(i)):
    print i
    s+=i
    ctr+=1
  i+=1

print s

lww=raw_input()
```

Comment: Did you perhaps just run off the end of the sieve?

Comment: That seems most likely. Do you know how large the 11th bidirectionally-truncatable prime is?

Comment: If you just add some code to catch the exception and `print n`, we'll actually _know_ if this is the problem instead of having to guess…

Comment: According to [A020994](http://oeis.org/A020994), the primes that are both left-truncatable and right-truncatable are 2, 3, 5, 7, 23, 37, 53, 73, 313, 317, 373, 797, 3137, 3797, 739397. So if his sieve and test are implemented correctly, they will all fit. (Still, good guess, @user2357112, even if it wasn't the answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your algorithm is incorrect. You are finding primes `p` such that `p` is truncatable right-to-left and `reverse(p)` is truncatable right-to-left.

The problem, however, asks you to find primes `p` such that `p` is truncatable right-to-left and `p` is truncatable left-to-right. Truncatability of `p` left-to-right is not equivalent to truncatability of `reverse(p)` right-to-left.

Consider the number given in the problem, `3797` - it is truncatable in both directions (and so your code should be catching it), but its reverse `7973` is not truncatable right-to-left, so your code rejects it. This should've tipped you off.

You'll need to get rid of `reverse` (because it serves no purpose here) and instead modify your checking code to truncate in *both* directions.

---

You get an `IndexError` because you run out of sieve - your code correctly computes that there are only 5 primes `p` less than 1 million such that `p` is truncatable right-to-left and `reverse(p)` is truncatable right-to-left. Since you don't break out of the loop by then (since `ctr < 11`), your code tries to access `sieve[len(sieve)]`, and hits the `IndexError`.

---

Also - and this is not really related to your problem - I take it you come from a C background or something like that. Your code is somewhat difficult to read because it does not conform to standard Python style conventions. Once you have solved this problem for yourself (in the spirit of Project Euler), please take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c45613220bf5036362ea) for my corrections to your implementation that 1.) make it work correctly; and 2.) are closer to standard Pythonic style.

Comment: yea actually i have done a bit of java , c and c++ , learnt python because of the ease of access and simpler coding(no data type and stuff)...seriously have no clue about python style conventions would be appreciable if you could suggest me a way to implement that in my python programs!

Comment: If you have some time, you should read [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is the authoritative document on Python style. In particular, take a look at the "Code lay-out" and "Naming conventions" sections. Most importantly for the moment, be consistent with your indentation - use 4 spaces for each level of indentation. Your code right now mixes 2-space and 4-space indents, and that can lead to nasty indentation bugs later on.